# Please explain text-align weirdness in mobile safari

Tags: css, mobile-safari, text-alignment

I have a simple login form which includes a 'Cancel' button, created with the following code:

```
var cancelButton = document.createElement("input"); 
cancelButton.setAttribute('type',"button");
cancelButton.setAttribute('value',"Cancel");
cancelButton.setAttribute("id", "user-cancel-button");
```

the css for the button is as follows:

```
#user-cancel-button{
  left: 3px;
  top:3px;
  text-align: center;   
  position: absolute;
```

}

In every desktop browser it looks fine, however, in Mobile safari the 'Cancel' text is always aligned to the right (even if I set text-align: left).

If, on the other hand, I add some padding to the button (padding: 1px) it renders as it should in mobile safari.  Can anyone explain what's going on?

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. Unfortunately for me adding padding does not fix the issue.

I'm only have this problem in Mobile Safari 4.0.5 and under (iPhone 4/4.1 and below)

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this (jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/B3V4x/) on my iPad 3 but: text-align might only align the value inside the button. It looks like left: 3px; isn't being honored. Have you tried with a right value (auto or something large)?

Answer (score 0):

try doing this:

```
<button id="user-cancel-button"><div align="center">cancel</div><button>
```

This should solve the problem with the mobile safari.